# Как отформатировать вывод?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как отформатировать вывод? не получается все выровнять как надо

```
import random

print("{0:4}|{1:4}|{2}".format("a", "b", "c"))
for i in range(5):
    a = random.randint(1, 100000)
    b = random.randint(1, 100000)
    c = random.randint(1, 100000)
    print("{0:4}|{1:4}|{2}".format(a, b, c))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте str.center(width, [fill])

Comment: как это совместить с format?

Comment: сделайте абц сразу нужными строками длинны 5

Comment: _не получается все выровнять как надо_ - а как надо?

Comment: `"{0:6}|{1:6}|{2:6}"`

Comment: pip install PrettyTable

Comment: если значения не большие как в примере можно обойтись табуляцией.
например `print("{0:4}\t|{1:4}\t|{2}".format("a", "b", "c"))`